# Converting equation of Cissoid to polar coordinates

Tags: trigonometry

Convert the equation of the Cissoid: $(4-x)^2y^2=x^3$ in to polar coordinates.

I know to convert it into polar coordinates first, by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Otherwise I don't know where to continue after that.

Comment: Just substitute $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ into the given Cartesian equation to get your polar equation.

Comment: Your function is a polynomial with a power of 3.  I don't believe it can be converted into polar coordinates by any easy means.  Polynomials of powers 1 and 2 can be converted via $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, unlike yours.  Also, use \sqrt with { and } around $x^2+y^2$ inside.  Place "$" on the outside of \sqrt.  Use \function{whatever_you_want_inside} format.

Comment: @learner does that seriously work?

Comment: @SimpleArt, yes, because that's how the Cartesian and polar systems are related. You can prove it yourselves very easily by a geometric setup.

Comment: @SimpleArt, I made the geometric setup for you. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/ejbb6eX.png). The point $(x,y)$ in Cartesian coordinates is the same as the point $(r,\theta)$ in polar representation. Using basic trigonometry, you can get the expressions for $x,y$ in terms of $r,\theta$.

Comment: Never actually done it.  I've always done polar$\to$cartesian, never the other way around, except with circles.  Using trigonometric identities of course.

Comment: Thank you learner.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the substitutions
$$x=r\cos\theta \quad y=r\sin\theta$$
which gives you
$$(4-r\cos\theta)^2(r\sin\theta)^2=(r\cos\theta)^3$$
You can try to multiply this expression out and simplify, but it's probably best to leave it as this.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* a cissoid of Diocles, as the latter is a rational cubic curve, and yours is a quartic curve.